# не отображается индикатор загрузки ubuntu перед входом в систему

Tags: linux, ubuntu

такое поведение наблюдается после свежей установки ubuntu 16.04 LTS на ноут от dell.

Ожидается, что перед входом в систему при включении или перезагрузке ОС должно показыватся состояние загрузки с помощью индикатора как на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но вместо этого пустой экран на этом фоне без ничего.
Заметил иногда этот индикатор появляется на доли секунды перез входом в систему, а иногда нет (но в большинстве случаев не появляется вовсе)

Скажите, это нормально или баг ??

и если баг то как исправить ?

Comment: Возможно, у тебя заело кнопку на клавиатуре...

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр какую кнопу ?

Comment: Вообще любую. Если при загрузке ubuntu нажать на какую-либо клавишу, то будет показан лог. При следующем нажатии вернется анимация

Comment: Вот я и думаю, что это аппаратная проблема

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр понажимал на клавишы ничего не изменилось

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр а какая тут аппаратная проблема может быть ?

Comment: Вот мыл ты клаву, отодрал криво контрл, сунул обратно и его защимило. Будто он свегда нажат

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр клаву не мыл никогда , она герметизированная

Comment: Запусти виртуалку и попробуй зажать кнопку во время загрузки Ubuntu, получишь тот же эффект

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр ну, для таких танцов времени нет. Ещё вот заметил иногда после перезагрузки рушится gnome-software говорит internal bug и software center запускается и тутже закрывается - я почему то виню  драйвер видеокарты, из за него все эти баги включаяя баг с индикатором перед входом

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй переустановить прогу, которая и делает анимацию...
sudo apt-get remove plymouth
sudo apt-get install plymouth